# Testing for Upper and Lowercase in Java

Tags: java, uppercase, lowercase

I need to create a Java program named `UpperOrLower` that asks a user to type a number 
and prints "*Uppercase or lowercase: true*" if the unicode character with that number 
is either uppercase or lowercase and "*Uppercase or lowercase: false*" otherwise.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UpperOrLower {
        public static void main(String args[]) {

                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
                int value = input.nextInt();
                char digit = (char) value;
                boolean isUpperOrLower =
                        (Character.isUpperCase || Character.isLowerCase);

                System.out.println("Uppercase or Lowercase: " +isUpperOrLower);

        }
}
```

Here's what I have, I keep getting errors, and I have no idea how to fix them.

Comment: You should at least include *what* errors you're getting. Have you looked at the API documentation for the methods you're trying to call? (And they are methods, that take parameters; hint.)

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
boolean isUpperOrLower = Character.isUpperCase(digit) || Character.isLowerCase(digit);
```

`isUpperCase` and `isLowerCase` are static methods of the `Character` class that take `char`s as arguments.

You could also do:

```
boolean isUpperOrLower = (digit >= 'A' && digit <= 'z')
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Character.isUpperCase(char c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase%28char%29) takes in a character. You need to call the method passing in your character so it knows what it is testing on.

```
boolean isUpperOrLower =
                    (Character.isUpperCase(digit) || Character.isLowerCase(digit));
```

Comment: Java 1.4 is way outdated. You should link to at least Java 1.6.

Comment: Thanks for that, it now has a shiny new link

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UpperOrLower { public static void main(String args[]) {

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
            int value = input.nextInt();
            char digit = (char) value;
            boolean isUpperOrLower =
                    (Character.isUpperCase (digit) || Character.isLowerCase(digit));
            System.out.println("The Charecter is: " +digit);
            System.out.println("Uppercase or Lowercase: " +isUpperOrLower);

    }
}
```